# voice command to capture photo

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I use `Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture` in my Windows Phone 8.1 app to capture a photo. Instead of a button, I'd like to trigger the photo capturing process by a voice command (for example, if the user says 'cheese'). How can I detect such a voice command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [SpeechRecognizer class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.media.speechrecognition.speechrecognizer.aspx).

Here's a sample from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn630427.aspx):

```
private async void StartRecognizing_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Create an instance of SpeechRecognizer.
    var speechRecognizer = new Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognizer();

    // Compile the dictation grammar by default.
    await speechRecognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();

    // Start recognition.
    Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognitionResult speechRecognitionResult = await speechRecognizer.RecognizeWithUIAsync();

    // Do something with the recognition result.
    var messageDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(speechRecognitionResult.Text, "Text spoken");
    await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
}
```